# Angular JS Node JS Bad request error post

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs with node js as server.

I am passing data this way from UI.

```
schatApp.controller('registerController', function($scope,$location,$http) {

    $scope.RegisterCredentials=function(){         
     var data={
            "firstName":"simhachalamrsdafrds",
            "lastName":"ajay",
            "username":"asfsd",
            "email":"ajayfds14@m.com",
            "provider":"local",
            "displayName":"amruth"
        }    

      // var json = "{\"firstName\": \"firstName\",\"lastName\": \"lastName\",\"username\": \"username\",\"email\": \"email\"}";

           var config = {
                headers : {
                      contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json'
                 }
            }    

        $http.post("/register",JSON.stringify(data),config).then(function sucess(result){   
      //  alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        },function failure(result){
         //   alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        });
    }
});
```

This is my backend code

```
app.post('/register',function(req,res){      
   var data={
     firstName:'simhachalam',
     lastName:'ajay',
     username:'asfsdq',
     email:'ajayfds14@mq.com',
     provider:'local',
     displayName:'amruth'  
     } 
console.log("111..............."); 
//console.log(req.body);  

//res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
core.account.create('local',data,function(err){  
if (err) { 
 var message = 'Sorry, we could not process your request';
   if (err.code === 11000) {
     message = 'Email has already been taken';
   }
   return res.status(400).json({
              status: 'error',
               message: message
               });
   }     
   res.status(201).json({  
                    status: 'success',
                    message: 'You\'ve been registered, ' +
                             'please try logging in now!'
                    });
}); 

});
```

I am getting 400 bad request.

Comment: You should check `err`

Comment: Server side, your `res.status(201)` comes after a `return res.status(400)` and will never be executed. There should be an `else` to `if (err)` ...

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to say what could be the issue, you need to do a console.log(err) object. can you give that information for us here.

```
if (err) { 
 var message = 'Sorry, we could not process your request';
   if (err.code === 11000) {
     message = 'Email has already been taken';
            }
     return res.status(400).json({
          status: 'error',
          message: message
     });
}
```

The above code clearly states that you are returning `res.status(400)`, can you change your $http.post to below and check.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "/register",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
});
```

hopefully your `/register endpoint` is hosted on the same server where you are serving the client from.